# How update orders by using woocommerce api in node js

Tags: node.js, angular, woocommerce-rest-api

```
exports.UpdateOrder = (req, res) => {
  const data = {
    status: "completed"
  };
  WooCommerce.put("orders/3217", data)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(JSON.parse(response.body));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    });
};
```

getting error 
TypeError: WooCommerce.put(...).then is not a function

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Perhaps try the promified method? https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api#promified-methods

Comment: woocommerce-api version `1.5.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using promisified methods such as in this example https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api#promified-methods

> Promified Methods
>   Every method can be used in a promified way just adding Async to the method name. Like in:

```
WooCommerce.getAsync('products').then(function(result) {
  return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
});
```

Comment: how update data by using Promified methods.can i get one example

Comment: ` WooCommerce.getAsync("orders/3217", data)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(JSON.parse(response.body));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    });`

tried  Promified .but getting errors

Comment: yeah i just edited my post

In your case you'd make it `putAsync` but right